# Why does get fail to find object in gamm, yet it works in lm?

Tags: r, function, get, gam, mgcv

I am struggling with writing an R function that calls a variable using `get()`

Suppose I have this data frame:

```
mydat = data.frame(y = rnorm(100), 
                   x = rnorm(100), 
                   day = sample(90:260, 100, replace = T), 
                   r1 = sample(seq(2008,2015,1), 100, replace = T),
                   r2 = sample(letters, 100, replace = T), 
                   r3 = sample(letters, 100, replace = T))
```

and I would like to write a function that returns the summary of a gamm model, e.g like this

```
gamm_summary = function(data, response = "y"){
    require(mgcv)
    gamm_model = gamm(get(response) ~ s(day),
                      random = list(r1=~1, r2=~1, r3 =~1), data = data, method = "REML")

    summary(gamm_model$gam)
}


gamm_summary(mydat)
```

Why does this give me the error:

> Error in get(response) : object 'response' not found

yet the following works:

```
lm_summary = function(data, response = "y") {
    lm_model = lm(get(response) ~ x, data = data)
    summary(lm_model)
}

lm_summary(mydat)
```

Q: Why does get fail to work in my gamm function and how could I rewrite the function so that it works?

Comment: try with this function `?reformulate`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
require(mgcv)
gamm_summary = function(mydata, a1 = "y", b1 = "day", rnd1 = "r1", rnd2 = "r2", rnd3 = "r3"){
    df = data.frame(aa = mydata[[a1]], bb = mydata[[b1]], rnd1 = mydata[[rnd1]], rnd2 = mydata[[rnd2]], rnd3 = mydata[[rnd3]])
    gamm_model = gamm(aa ~ s(bb), data = df, random = list(rnd1 =~ 1, rnd2 =~ 1, rnd3 =~ 1), method = "REML")
    summary(gamm_model$gam)
}

gamm_summary(mydat, a1 = "x")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was helpful, although it doesn't actually work. It seems to work because you used the same name for the response variable that you created as the original response variable name. If you replace within your function y by z you will get an error. However using data$z = data[,response] instead of z = data$response will work.